# Is an Angular application within an Angular application possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my opinion, this might not be possible but I'm asking this here to see if anyone thinks this is possible and also knows a way of doing this. So here it goes:

What I'm basically trying to achieve is that, there is an e-commerce website and than there is my Angular application which is supposed to add functionality to that e-commerce website. My angular application basically opens in a Bootstrap modal style layout and has several pages.

I inject my Angular application into the e-commerce website and everything works fine if the e-commerce website is not Angular based but if the e-commerce website is also Angular based, routes starts to conflict between my application and the e-commerce website.

Does anyone think that this might be possible? If so, how?
Please do let me know if I didn't make myself clear so that maybe I can improve my explanation.

Comment: If your application is using angular routing to intercept browser navigation, then this will likely cause issues with the e-commerce site.

Comment: @navigator my application is using the ui.router... which is exactly the reason why I think there would be troubles but still wanted to see if anyone else has any idea that might work.

Comment: if you show modal - why you need ui-router?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov the app has multiple pages like dashboard, account settings, etc. In short, my whole application lives within a modal.

Comment: but you cant have url in modal - why u need ui-router?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov but I can change modals content based on the route. I need ui-router for multiple pages in the modal.

Comment: Well, if you want to use it... use it. but this is wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. find and replace your the word "angular" in your angular js file then declare :

```
var app = custom-name-here.module('myapp',[]);
```

Option 2 . In theory : You should be able to wrap your content/ call scripts and css in an iframe .. This should allow you to protect your code from the outside .  This will also give you a little trouble communicating with the outside but can be easily done with script .

```
<iframe id="protected-content">

<link rel="stylesheet"...href="styles.css">

//html content here

<script src="..angular.min.js"><script>
<iframe>
```

Another option I'm not totally for sure about is Content-Security-Policy . Which in theory should let you add `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'` on div to protect that element from being affected by scripts outside the element. Follow this link : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a fan of the iframe, so I don't think that it would be the appropriate solution.

Comment: How would the Option 1 help exactly? Wouldn't both application still rely on the same URL causing routing troubles?
I guess your thinking that both Angular application are conflicting with each other, but they are not. Only there routes are.

Comment: You stated "everything works fine if the e-commerce website is not Angular based " in your question .. based on that statement everything above is still a possible solution . Option 1 , you'll need to test it . Otherwise provide code for us to see .